# Where to save cross application info on mac

Tags: java, macos, registry

I have application A that needs to launch application B.

The user can choose where to install B. This means that I need a way for A to know the path of where B is located.

B and A are installed separately and there is no assurance which one will be installed first or even that both are installed.

This means the installer of B has to write to some common public place the path where B was installed so A can later read this and find B.

My applications are written in Java and might be installed both on Windows and Mac.

On windows the solution is to write the path to the registry. I'm new to Mac. What is the right way to do this on Mac.

Where can one application write data that another application can read?

Thanks,
Shahar

Comment: I would at least have default pathways set for each OS, that way the user doesn't necessarily have to choose where the installs go and then your program can search those initial defaults.

Answer (score 2):

My answer would be something like:

Depends on if the application is going to run in a per-user context or a per-computer (i.e. for all users) context.

This seems like some kind of preference or setting that you'd want to write a preference file into the user's "Preferences" folder, which is usually found at `/Users/_______/Library/Preferences/` (fill the `_____` blank in with the user's account name).

I'm not sure if this would work from Java though.  How does the Java app get installed?  Downloaded from the browser or?

Comment: The applications are installed once for all users and run per user (its a UI app). The user install the application from disk and not from the internet.

Comment: I would argue that `Preferences` should only contain `plist` files.  If you wanted directory for free-form data (likely in a cross-platform app), I would suggest `~/Library/Application Support/<Application Name>`

Comment: Hi @EdwardThomson; sure, 'Application Support' would work as well (I don't recall seeing anywhere that Apple prefers all files in `Preferences` to be plist, tho). If Shahar is installing from disk, he could potentially use a Mac-specific PackageMaker installer (whee!) and then he could have root/admin access momentarily to install the settings files into `/Library/Application Support/` (or `/Library/Preferences`), which are places for settings to be shared across *all* users of a machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your installer for write a System Environment Variable like PROD_B_HOME. Then you can read the variable from Java.

From: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html

On the Java platform, an application uses System.getEnv to retrieve environment variable values. Without an argument, getEnv returns a read-only instance of java.util.Map, where the map keys are the environment variable names, and the map values are the environment variable values. This is demonstrated in the EnvMap example:

```
import java.util.Map;

public class EnvMap {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
        for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
            System.out.format("%s=%s%n",
                              envName,
                              env.get(envName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be “native,” you can call Launch Services to find an application based upon its Bundle ID — this requires that the application to be “found” is in a `.app` bundle and has a proper (`com.yourname.appname` type) identifier assigned. You should be able to call the `LSFindApplicationForInfo` from a shell script — there appears to be a small binary wrapper for it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the information of applications installed on a Mac is stored under a "Receipts" folder.

- for Mac 10.6 : /private/var/db/Receipts,
- for Mac 10.5: /Library/Receipts/,

so you do not have to do anything different within the installer of B, you can simply go through the above receipts folder and find the relevant package (*.pkg) with any language within A, the real path of that application can be found at **info.plist** file under contents folder of that .pkg file.

hope it helps.